# Upload invoice to sharepoint

Tags: powershell, office-365, azure

Is there a way to programmatically upload to SharePoint all the invoices related to my tenant (M365, Azure) with all facts like amount, vat? I have a manual process now, but it would be great if I could skip this monhly task.
E-mail + Power automate solves half of the problem, the upload.

Answer (score 1):

If your invoices are of a consistent format (formatting of the invoice is the same), take a look at [SharePoint Syntex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/contentunderstanding) which can extract the contents of say the company invoiced, amount, and so forth and add it to a Document Library column.

You would still need to take the emailed invoices and use Power Automate to place it in the proper library, of course.

Comment: These are the standard Office 365 invoices. I was hoping that the information in the invoice is available directly somehow.